# Lemon Parser REPL

Tags: parsing, grammar, lemon

I'm trying to build a Smalltalk REPL based on [LanguageKit](https://github.com/etoile/Languages), which uses a lemon gramma. Currently the parser only supports parsing complete class definitions, but not statements outside of the method syntax.

For example this gets parsed:

```
methodName [
    NSObject description.
    NSObject debugDescription.
]
```

But it will fail if I try to parse only the statements:

```
NSObject description.
NSObject debugDescription.
```

The following won't accept multiple statements (e.g. `Transcript show: 'hello'. Transcript show: 'world'.`):

```
file ::= statement_list(M).
{
    [p setAST:M];
}
```

Here the minimal gramma:

```
%include {
#include <assert.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <LanguageKit/LanguageKit.h>
#import <LanguageKit/LKToken.h>
#import "SmalltalkParser.h"

}
%name SmalltalkParse
%token_prefix TOKEN_
%token_type {id}
%extra_argument {SmalltalkParser *p}
%left PLUS MINUS STAR SLASH EQ LT GT COMMA.
%left WORD.


file ::= method(M).
{
    [p setAST:M];
}
file ::= statement_list(M).
{
    [p setAST:M];
}
file ::= statement(M).
{
    [p setAST:M];
}
file ::= .



method(M) ::= signature(S) LSQBRACK statement_list(E) RSQBRACK.
{
    M = [LKInstanceMethod methodWithSignature:S locals:nil statements:E];
}

signature(S) ::= WORD(M).
{
    S = [LKMessageSend messageWithSelectorName:M];
}
signature(S) ::= keyword_signature(M).
{
    S = M;
}


statement_list(L) ::= statements(T).
{
    L = T;
}
statement_list(L) ::= statements(T) statement(S).
{
    [T addObject:S];
    L = T;
}

statements(L) ::= statements(T) statement(S) STOP.
{
    [T addObject:S];
    L = T;
}
statements(L) ::= .
{
    L = [NSMutableArray array];
}

statement(S) ::= expression(E).
{
    S = E;
}

%syntax_error 
{
    [NSException raise:@"ParserError" format:@"Parsing failed"];
}

message(M) ::= simple_message(S).
{
    M = S;
}

simple_message(M) ::= WORD(S).
{
    M = [LKMessageSend messageWithSelectorName:S];
}

expression(E) ::= simple_expression(S).
{
    E = S;
}

simple_expression(E) ::= WORD(T) simple_message(M).
{
    [M setTarget:T];
    E = M;
}
```

The complete gramma can be found here: [smalltalk.y](https://github.com/etoile/Languages/blob/master/Smalltalk/smalltalk.y). I have been reading other grammas and also searching stackoverflow, but don't see a difference for example with this [gramma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46840708/23028) and don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret "But it won't accept multiple statements." In your question, that is followed by a rule which indeed should accept multiple statements but does not appear anywhere in what you claim is the "complete" grammar. Please focus on the actual problem; don't include multiple copies of the grammar or vague indications about possible modifications. If you edit your question with an [mcve], it will be *much* easier to provide useful suggestions.

Comment: @rici Thank you for taking the time to look at this, really appreciated! I edited the question and hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar has parsing conflicts. These must be resolved if you have a hope of getting the grammar to work correctly.

(The grammar also has an undefined non-terminal, `keyword_signature`, and an unused non-terminal `message`. To get it to compile without warnings, I simply removed them. I don't think it makes any difference to the analysis below.)

Part of the conflict is very simple: you cannot have both

```
file ::= statement_list .
```

and

```
file ::= statement .
```

In fact, it is not clear to me why you would want to? Isn't a `statement` an example of a `statement_list`?

The reason you cannot have both is that you have:

```
 statement_list ::= statements statement .
```

and

```
 statements ::= .
```

Taken together, that means that starting with `statement_list`, you can recognise a single `statement`. So your grammar is ambiguous; if the input is a single statement, it could be directly parsed as a `file` or it could be parsed as `file` ⇒ `statement_list` ⇒ `statements statement` ⇒ `statement`, with a different set of actions.

You might not care; indeed, you might believe that the sequence of actions is identical. You might even be right about that. But the parser cannot know that, and it will not believe it. It sees the two parses as necessarily distinct. So it will report a conflict.

In short, get rid of `file ::= statement .`. Then you can start working on the other parsing conflicts.

---

The more fundamental problem is also based on the fact that `statements` can derive the empty sequence.

Let's take a look at the grammar (simplified by removing all semantics):

```
statement_list ::= statements .
statement_list ::= statements statement .
statements     ::= statements statement STOP .
statements     ::= .
```

If `statement_list` is not empty, whatever it matches must start with an empty `statements` followed by a `statement`. `statement`, in turn, must start with `WORD`, so `statement_list` must match input which starts with `WORD`. But before it can shift the `WORD` in order to continue the parse, it needs to first insert the empty `statements`. So it needs to do a reduction using the last rule quoted above before it can handle a `WORD`. (If this paragraph is not completely clear, please try rereading it, and if you still have questions, ask. It's important to understand this part.)

None of that would be a problem if it were not for the fact that `file` could also be a `method`, and `method` also starts with a `WORD`. But, unlike `statement_list`, it really starts with `WORD`. It does not start with an empty `statements`, so if the parser creates an empty `statements` and the input is actually a `method`, then the parse will fail.

As it happens, this particular conflict doesn't occur if you have `file ::= statement` instead of `file ::= statement_list`, because `statement` doesn't start with an empty `statements` either. That means that when the parser sees the `WORD` at the beginning of the input, it does not yet have to decide whether it is about to see a `statement` or a `method`. In both cases, the parse action is to shift the `WORD` and see what comes next.

To solve this problem, we can observe that `statement_list` must contain at least one `statement`, and that all the `statement`s inside a `statement_list` (except possibly the last one) must be terminated with a `STOP` (that is, <kbd>.</kbd>). If we start with that idea, it's pretty easy to produce an alternative grammar which does not require an empty list at the beginning:

```
statement_list ::= statements .
statement_list ::= statements STOP .
statements ::= statement .
statements ::= statements STOP statement .
```

This differs from your grammar in that it considers a `statement_list` to be a non-empty list of dot-separated `statement`s optionally terminated with a dot, while your grammar considers a statement_list to be a possibly empty list of dot-terminated `statement`s followed by a single `statement`.

---

Since I have now tested the grammar, I add the complete testable code as an illustration of what we ask for when we ask for a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (I used C and flex rather than Objective C but I don't think that makes any difference.)

File parser.y:

```
%include { #include <assert.h> }
file ::= method.
file ::= statement_list.
file ::= .
method ::= signature OBRAC statement_list CBRAC .
signature ::= WORD .
statement_list ::= statements STOP .
statement_list ::= statements .
statements ::= statements STOP statement .
statements ::= statement .
statement ::= expression .
expression ::= simple_expression .
simple_expression ::= WORD simple_message .
simple_message ::= WORD .
%extra_argument { int* status }
%syntax_error { *status = 1; }
%parse_failure { fprintf(stderr, "Parse failed.\n"); }
%parse_accept { fprintf(stderr, "Parse succeeded.\n"); }
```

File main.l:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "parser.h"
void* ParseAlloc(void* (*allocProc)(size_t));
void* Parse(void*, int, int, int*);
void* ParseFree(void*, void(*freeProc)(void*));

void synerr(const char* token) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error handling '%s'\n", token);
}
%}
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault
%x FLUSH
%%
    void* parser = ParseAlloc(malloc);
    int status = 0;
    #define SEND(typ, val) do {                        \
       if (Parse(parser, typ, val, &status), status) { \
         synerr(yytext); BEGIN(FLUSH);                 \
       }                                               \
    } while(0)
[[:space:]]+ ;
[[:alnum:]]+ { SEND(WORD, 0); }
"["          { SEND(OBRAC, 0); }
"]"          { SEND(CBRAC, 0); }
"."          { SEND(STOP, 0); }
.            { synerr(yytext); BEGIN(FLUSH); }
<FLUSH>.+    ;
<FLUSH>\n    { status = 0; BEGIN(INITIAL); }
<<EOF>>      { if (status == 0) {
                 Parse(parser, 0, 0, &status);
                 if (status) synerr("EOF");
               }
               ParseFree(parser, free );
               return 0;
             }
%%

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   return yylex();
}
```

Build procedure:

```
$ lemon parser.y
$ flex -o main.c main.l
$ gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -o catlan -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=800 main.c parser.c
```

Tests:

```
$ ./catlan <<< 'NSObject'
Parse failed.
Syntax error handling 'EOF'
$ ./catlan <<< 'NSObject description'
Parse succeeded.
$ ./catlan <<< 'NSObject description.'
Parse succeeded.
$ ./catlan <<< 'NSObject description. OtherObject'
Parse failed.
Syntax error handling 'EOF'
$ ./catlan <<< 'NSObject description. OtherObject otherDesc'
Parse succeeded.
$ ./catlan <<< 'NSObject description. OtherObject otherDesc.'
Parse succeeded.
$ ./catlan <<< 'NSObject description. OtherObject otherDesc extra words'
Syntax error handling 'extra'
Parse succeeded.
$ ./catlan <<< 'method [ NSObject desc]'
Parse succeeded.
$ ./catlan <<< 'method [ NSObject desc.]'
Parse succeeded.
$ ./catlan <<< 'method [ NSObject desc extra words]'
Syntax error handling 'extra'
Parse failed.
$ ./catlan <<< 'method [ NSObject desc. Second]'
Syntax error handling ']'
Parse failed.
$ ./catlan <<< 'method [ NSObject desc. Second desc]'
Parse succeeded.
```

Comment: Thank you. After you mentioned the warning I figured out that my Xcode build setup wasn't showing me [lemon warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54803222/23028).

The grammar you suggest does work and applies the _"list of dot-separated statements optionally terminated with a dot"_ rule in methods, but outside of methods the termination with a dot is **required**. Works: `test [ NSObject description ]` Fails: `NSObject description. NSObject description`

Comment: @catlan: does your grammar now show no warnings? Did you remove 'file ::= statement .`?

Comment: Yes it is now warnings free. https://gist.github.com/catlan/b1fbc88793b66c86f8942c4b1077e877

Comment: @catlan: Works fine for me. Of course, I had to invent a lexer so it might not be exactly the same as yours. By the way, the test at line 55 is unnecessary and possibly dangerous. You should unconditionally assign `L` as a new empty array.

Comment: you are right, your gramma is fine. Still not comfortable with lemon, fighting with comments now, but need to wrap my head around it.

Comment: do you have any book for article recommendation on this?